# Storing an array of dictionary objects in an application() object - Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Using Classic ASP, does anyone know if it is possible (or advisable) to put an array of dictionary objects into an Application Object?  I tried but after about 50,000 or so hits to the script below the App Pool gets corrupted or something and "trappable" C0000005 errors get generated when this line is run: dictLanguage=Application("lang")

Works fine for a few days though.  Is it something to do with the way I've assigned the application object to another variable, I thought it would pass a pointer not a copy?  Anyone smarter than me know what's going on here?

```
if isempty(Application("lang")) then 
    ''# called when first visitor hits the page (following server reboot or app pool recycle)
    init()
    dictLanguage=Application("lang")
else
    ''# called for all other page hits
    dictLanguage=Application("lang") ''# ***** TRAPPABLE ERROR after a few thousand page views *******
end if


''# // fill the application object with an array containing 10 dictionary objects, each holding a different language.
''# // This function appears to run just fine.

function init

    Set initcn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    initcn.Open dbConStr
    strSQL = "SELECT languageNo,quickRef,text FROM tblTranslation"
    Set rs = initcn.Execute(strSQL) 

    dim d(10)   

    Set d(1)=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d(2)=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d(3)=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d(4)=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d(5)=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d(6)=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d(7)=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d(8)=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d(9)=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d(10)=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    while not rs.eof
        a=rs("languageNo")
        b=rs("quickRef")
        c=rs("text")
        ''# on error resume next
        d(a).Add b,c    
        rs.movenext
    wend

    initcn.close

    ''# Storing the array in the Application object
    Application.Lock
    Application("lang") = d
    Application.Unlock

end function
```

Comment: I would put something that big in a database or file.

Comment: it's already in a database.  I'm trying to cache the data in the application object for speed.  Requerying our database on every page would kill performance.

Comment: Then i would use `.GetRows()`

Comment: @AnthonyWJones you can prettify the code also by adding `<!-- language: lang-vbs -->` on top of the code, learned it after long experiments.

Comment: David - you can store raw string of data or plain arrays in application level, then parse them to Dictionary at run time on every request - shouldn't be too complicated let me know if you need a hand.

Comment: I solved the issue by dumping the translations directly into the application scope with a prefix for each language application("ln3_ref") = "Some text" which works pretty quickly unless there are tens of thousands of translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use Dictionary objects as application-level variables due to their threading model. If you need to use a Dictionary-like object in the application-level use the free Lookup Component from Microsoft (or a free Dictionary Component from Caprock Consulting).

To learn more, please visit [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20061026092009/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=129) url.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the links in that URL are all dead but that's definitely the answer to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

One object that is readily available and supports being stored in the application object has the ProgID "MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0"

This is a pretty good solution to loading fairly static application wide data, if you are using SQL Server then SQL Servers `FOR XML` feature makes it fairly easy to build some XML to load into the DOM.